# R - How to get a difference/sum of 2 step functions?

Tags: r

I have 2 step function objects (ecdf objects to be exact). How to calculate a step function that is a difference or sum of these two?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you please provide a [reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I disagree with the calls for a reproducible example -- this is a simple factual question.

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744641/5784831)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends on what you need it for.  An object of class `stepfun` is in one sense a function; if `a <- ecdf(rnorm(100))`, then `a(0)` will evaluate to something close to `.5`.  So you can add them just by adding functions -- `ecdf.sum <- function(x) { ecdf1(x) + ecdf2(x) }`. This will yield something that is effectively a step function, but not of class `stepfun` or `ecdf`.

Regardless, what you get out will not be an `ecdf` object, because the values will not have the correct range.  But to at least recover it as a step function, you can decompose it into knots:

```
knots.new <- sort(knots(ec1), knots(ec2))
ec.new <- stepfun(knots.new, c(0,ec1(knots.new) + ec2(knots.new)))
```

The `c(0, ...` is because you need one more value than the knots (for the left-hand value of the step function), and for objects of type `ecdf` 0 is a safe value.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and found the follwoing nice solution

```
y1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0)
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
f1 <- stepfun(x = x1, y = y1)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
plot(f1)

y2 <- c(0, 1, 0)
x2 <- c(1.5, 2.5)
f2 <- stepfun(x = x2, y = y2)
plot(f2)

fs <- function(x, f1, f2) {
  return(f1(x) + f2(x))
}

fm <- function(x, f1, f2) {
  return(f1(x) * f2(x))
}

x <- seq(0, 4, length.out = 100)
plot(x, fs(x, f1, f2), type = "s", main = "Sum f1+f2")
plot(x, fm(x, f1, f2), type = "s", main = "Multiplication f1*f2")

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

There might be a more elegant version using `+` and `*` operators, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788801/5784831)...

```
foo <- structure(list(value = 1, txt = 'a'), class = 'foo')
`+.foo` <- function(leftfoo, rightfoo) { return (paste(leftfoo$txt, rightfoo$txt)) }

foo + foo
#[1] "a a"
```