# How can a make the sum of two step functions (R-stepfun) of class "stepfun"?

Tags: r, function, class

From the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69738109/5784831) I tried to make the sum as class "stepfun". I thought, `as.stepfun` is the right choice, but my ideas don't work. What is wrong?

```
y1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0)
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
f1 <- stepfun(x = x1, y = y1)
print(class(f1))
# [1] "stepfun"  "function" #  OK!!!
plot(f1)

y2 <- c(0, 1, 0)
x2 <- c(1.5, 2.5)
f2 <- stepfun(x = x2, y = y2)
plot(f2)

fs <- function(x, f1, f2) {
  # y <- f1(x) + f2(x) #  OK
  # y <- as.stepfun(x = x, y = y, ties = "ordered", right = FALSE) # does not work
  # return(y) #           does not work
  return(f1(x) + f2(x))
}
print(class(fs)) # [1] "function"
# attributes(fs) # no new information...

fm <- function(x, f1, f2) {
  return(f1(x) * f2(x))
}
print(class(fm)) # [1] "function"
```

---

Example `as.` for  `data.frame` which works as expected:

```
z <- c(1, 2)
class(z) #    [1] "numeric"
class(as.data.frame(z)) #    [1] "data.frame"
```

---

About internals of `stepfun`

```
function (x, y, f = as.numeric(right), ties = "ordered", right = FALSE) 
{
  if (is.unsorted(x)) 
    stop("stepfun: 'x' must be ordered increasingly")
  n <- length(x)
  if (n < 1) 
    stop("'x' must have length >= 1")
  n1 <- n + 1L
  if (length(y) != n1) 
    stop("'y' must be one longer than 'x'")
  rval <- approxfun(x, y[-if (right) 
    n1
  else 1], method = "constant", yleft = y[1L], yright = y[n1], 
    f = f, ties = ties)
  class(rval) <- c("stepfun", class(rval))
  attr(rval, "call") <- sys.call()
  rval
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the answers from @jblood94, @user2554330 and @rbm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788801/5784831) I found an elegant way which I plan to use in my case. I hope that also helps others:

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
y1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0)
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
f1 <- stepfun(x = x1, y = y1)

y2 <- c(0, 1, 0)
x2 <- c(1.5, 2.5)
f2 <- stepfun(x = x2, y = y2)

plot(f1)
plot(f2)

'+.stepfun' <- function(f1, f2) {
  xs1 <- get("x", envir = environment(f1))
  xs2 <- get("x", envir = environment(f2))
  xs <- sort(unique(c(x1, x2)))
  ys <- f1(c(xs[1] - 1, xs)) + f2(c(xs[1] - 1, xs))
  return(stepfun(x = xs, y = ys))
}
f1 + f2
print(class(f1 + f2))
plot(f1 + f2, main = "Sum f1+f2")

'*.stepfun' <- function(f1, f2) {
  xs1 <- get("x", envir = environment(f1))
  xs2 <- get("x", envir = environment(f2))
  xs <- sort(unique(c(x1, x2)))
  ys <- f1(c(xs[1] - 1, xs)) * f2(c(xs[1] - 1, xs))
  return(stepfun(x = xs, y = ys))
}
f1 * f2
print(class(f1 * f2))
plot(f1 * f2, main = "Sum f1*f2")

par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

Comment: Very nice overloading.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like user2554330 is right about creating `stepfun` objects directly from two other `stepfun` objects, but here is a workaround in case it's useful:

```
x12 <- sort(unique(c(x1, x2)))
y12 <- f1(c(x12[1] - 1, x12)) + f2(c(x12[1] - 1, x12))
fs <- stepfun(x = x12, y = y12)
```

UPDATE1:

Or if you want to create the function from `f1` and `f2`:

```
fs <- function(f1, f2) {
  xs <- sort(unique(c(get("x", envir = environment(f1)), get("x", envir = environment(f2)))))
  ys <- f1(c(xs[1] - 1, xs)) + f2(c(xs[1] - 1, xs))
  return(stepfun(x = xs, y = ys))
}
plot(fs(f1, f2))
```

UPDATE2:

Or for an arbitrarily long list of `stepfun` objects and a the ability to specify the combining function:

```
y3 <- c(-1, 2, 1, 0)
x3 <- c(0.5, 1, 3)
f3 <- stepfun(x = x3, y = y3)

fs <- function(lf, fun) {
  xs <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(lf, function(x) get("x", envir = environment(x))))))
  ys <- apply(mapply(function(f) f(c(xs[1] - 1, xs)), lf), 1, FUN = fun)
  return(stepfun(x = xs, y = ys))
}
plot(fs(list(f1, f2, f3), "sum"))
plot(fs(list(f1, f2, f3), "prod"))
```

Comment: OK, another step :-) Just in case you see the answer (see also my edit to the question): Is it clear to you, how you can put all that into one function `fs <- function(f1, f2) {...}` which returns the sum as function of class `stepfun`?

Comment: @Christoph Sure, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help again! You might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744641/5784831 below ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The `fs` function needs the `"stepfun"` class, not the results it returns.  But your `fs` object won't work as a `"stepfun"` object, because R makes assumptions about those:  they need to keep copies of the data that produced them, among other things.  You can see what `f1` keeps by looking at `ls(environment(f1))`.  I don't know how those objects are used, but presumably they are needed.

Edited to add:

To turn `fs` into a `"stepfun"` object, you could try `as.stepfun(fs)`.  But this fails, with the error message

```
  Error in as.stepfun.default(fs) : 
no 'as.stepfun' method available for 'x'
```

The error message isn't the best (`x` is the internal name of the first argument, and in my opinion it would make more sense to say there's no method available for `fs`), but it's saying R doesn't know how to do the conversion you want.

Comment: OK... I just edited my question and added another `as.` example. 1) To me it seems that `as.stepfun` does not work as other `as.`-functions. Correct? 2) Your `ls(environment(f1))` shows e.g. `x`, the "breaks" and "y", the y-values of the stepfun. To me it seems, my approach might be really dangerous in the sense that unexpected behavior might occur later. (Step functions would be part of  larger package.). What do you think? Thank you for your support...

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69744641/5784831 below ;-)